# Changing mysql_fetch_array to PDO equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN (";

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
    $sql.=$id.",";
}

$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$totalprice=0;

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']*$row['price'];
    $totalprice+=$subtotal;
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?>$</td>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']*$row['price'] ?>$</td>
    </tr>
    <?php               
    }
?>
<tr>
    <td>Total Price: <?php echo $totalprice ?></td>
</tr>
```

This is the code I am using currently.
The obvious error I am getting is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()

I know I need to change it to PDO, but I am not sure what to replace `mysql_fetch_array` with while still getting the totalprice I want.
After changing it to this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
    $sql.=$id.",";
}

$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$totalprice=0;
```

I am unsure of how to proceed while still getting the correct total price

Comment: The `mysql_*` function has been removed, please take a look at either `PDO` or `MySQLi` on [php.net](http://php.net/).

Comment: With `PDO` `mysql_fetch_array()` is `$conn->fetchAll()` where `$conn` is the connection variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN (";

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
    $sql.=$id.",";
}

$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$totalprice=0;

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); # FOr mysql_fetch_assoc

foreach ($result as $index=>$arr) {
    // $val = $arr['key'];
}
```

Pure mysql way:

```
while ($row =  $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    // $val = $row['key'];
}
```

For mysql_fetch__array:

You can use PDO::FETCH_NUM

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

http://micmap.org/php-by-example/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.html

Comment: I am getting the error:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
At line: `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {`

Comment: This is beacue $_SESSION['cart'] should be an array. is not it array ?check the type of $_SESSION['cart'] by echo gettype($_SESSION['cart']);